# Proper method for opening files at a particular offset with Win32 api using c++

Tags: c++, file, winapi

Problem: Unsure of how to properly load data from a file starting at a given offset. The little snippet is a Win32 api wrapper for opening an xml file. The first method using SetFilePointer does not work. The issue being that it does not throw any warnings that it doesn't work either. The seekStatus doesn't return INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER.

What does'nt Work:

```
Utf16String* BinaryFile::Text()
{
    int readStatus = 0;
    size_t bufferSize = 12000000;
    wchar_t* buffer = static_cast<wchar_t*>(calloc(1,bufferSize));
    OVERLAPPED overlapped = {0};
    overlapped.Offset = 0;
    DWORD error;

    DWORD seekStatus = INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER;
    seekStatus = SetFilePointer(
                        fileHandle->Handle(),
                        2,
                        0,
                        FILE_BEGIN
                        );

    if(seekStatus == INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER)
    {
        error = GetLastError();
    }

    readStatus = ReadFileEx(
                        fileHandle->Handle(),
                        buffer,
                        bufferSize,
                        &overlapped,
                        FileIOCompletionRoutine
                        );

    if(!readStatus)
    {
        error = GetLastError();
    }
    

    Utf8String* string = new Utf16String(static_cast<wchar_t*>(buffer));
    
    return string;
}
```

What does work:

```
Utf16String* BinaryFile::Text()
{
    int readStatus = 0;
    size_t bufferSize = 12000000;
    wchar_t* buffer = static_cast<wchar_t*>(calloc(1,bufferSize));
    OVERLAPPED overlapped = {0};
    overlapped.Offset = 2;
    DWORD error;

    readStatus = ReadFileEx(
                        fileHandle->Handle(),
                        buffer,
                        bufferSize,
                        &overlapped,
                        FileIOCompletionRoutine
                        );

    if(!readStatus)
    {
        error = GetLastError();
    }
    

    Utf8String* string = new Utf16String(static_cast<wchar_t*>(buffer));
    
    return string;
}
```

Questions:

- Why Doesn't SetFilePointer appear to work?
- Is it possible to get the first method to work?
- Can the way that's working be accepted as the proper way?
- Could I run into possible problems using the second method?

Comment: *The first method using SetFilePointer does not work.*  -- What exactly do you mean by "does not work"?  In addition, you should indicate by what method you used to conclude that it doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], note that `error` is uninitialised

Comment: ReadFile "[Synchronization and file position](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile#synchronization-and-file-position)": "If lpOverlapped is not NULL, the read operation starts at the offset that is specified in the OVERLAPPED structure." The file position is used only when lpOverlapped is NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Why Doesn't SetFilePointer appear to work?*

because you specify offset by setting the `Offset` and `OffsetHigh` members of the `OVERLAPPED` structure. in this case it and used instead [`FILE_OBJECT::CurrentByteOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ns-wdm-_file_object) . all what doing `SetFilePointer` - set `CurrentByteOffset` in `FILE_OBJECT`

> *Is it possible to get the first method to work?*

the `SetFilePointer` absolute senseless api and atavism. it never must be used at all. ask your self - for what do separate call to kernel if possible set the same offset via `OVERLAPPED` ?

in case synchronous I/O file 2 api calls

```
SetFilePointer(hFile, lDistanceToMove, &lDistanceToMoveHigh, FILE_BEGIN);
ReadFile(hFile, *, *, *, &ov);
```

is equal by effect to single call

```
OVERLAPPED ov = { 0, 0, { lDistanceToMove, lDistanceToMoveHigh } };
ReadFile(hFile, *, *, *, &ov);
```

but first way is slow compare second, need more checks, etc

if file opened for asynchronous I/O ( `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` set in call `CreateFile`) we **always** must pass explicit byte offset in read/write operation (except named pipes and mailslots). if file opened for synchronous I/O - and you use `OVERLAPPED` parameter - possible **formal** do next

```
    OVERLAPPED ov {};
    ov.Offset = FILE_USE_FILE_POINTER_POSITION;
    ov.OffsetHigh = -1;
```

in this case will be used `FILE_OBJECT::CurrentByteOffset` (of course if synchronous I/O on file). `FILE_USE_FILE_POINTER_POSITION` defined in *wdm.h*

```
#define FILE_USE_FILE_POINTER_POSITION  0xfffffffe
```

from [`NtReadFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntreadfile)

> If the call to `NtCreateFile` set either of the *CreateOptions* flags
> `FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_ALERT` or `FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT`, the I/O
> Manager maintains the current file position. If so, the caller of
> `NtReadFile` can specify that the current file position offset be used
> instead of an explicit ByteOffset value. This specification can be
> made by using one of the following methods:
>
> - Specify a pointer to a `LARGE_INTEGER` value with the *HighPart* member    set to -1 and the *LowPart* member set to the system-defined
>   value    `FILE_USE_FILE_POINTER_POSITION`.
> - Pass a `NULL` pointer for *ByteOffset*.

so - if file created as asynchronous - no way at all.
if as synchronous - formal possible, but **bad and senseless**

> *Can the way that's working be accepted as the proper way?*

of course - use file offset in `OVERLAPPED` and proper way. use `SetFilePointer` - not proper and bad.

> *Could I run into possible problems using the second method?*

of course no. this and correct method and always must be used

Comment: Wow. Such detail. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> Why Doesn't SetFilePointer appear to work?

It does work.  But when you use `ReadFile/Ex()` with an `OVERLAPPED` struct, using `SetFilePointer()` to seek the file won't have the desired effect.  The file position will be set, but the read will simply ignore it and use the offset specified in the `OVERLAPPED` instead.

In your 1st code, you are setting the `OVERLAPPED` offset to `0`.  You are seeking the file to offset 2, but then reading from offset 0.  That is why the code does not work.

In the 2nd code, you are setting the `OVERLAPPED` offset to `2` instead. That is why the code works.

This is clearly explained in the `ReadFileEx()` documentation:

> For files that support byte offsets, **you must specify a byte offset at which to start reading from the file. You specify this offset by setting the `Offset` and `OffsetHigh` members of the [`OVERLAPPED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-overlapped) structure.** For files or devices that do not support byte offsets, `Offset` and `OffsetHigh` are ignored.

> Is it possible to get the first method to work?

Not when using an `OVERLAPPED` read, no.  You would have to remove the `OVERLAPPED` struct and switch to `ReadFile()` instead, then it will work, eg:

```cpp
Utf16String* BinaryFile::Text()
{
    int readStatus = 0;
    size_t bufferSize = 12000000;
    wchar_t* buffer = static_cast<wchar_t*>(calloc(1,bufferSize));
    DWORD error, dwNumRead;

    DWORD seekStatus = SetFilePointer(
                        fileHandle->Handle(),
                        2,
                        0,
                        FILE_BEGIN
                        );

    if (seekStatus == INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER)
    {
        error = GetLastError();
        free(buffer);
        return NULL;
    }

    readStatus = ReadFile(
                        fileHandle->Handle(),
                        buffer,
                        bufferSize,
                        &dwNumRead,
                        NULL
                        );

    if (!readStatus)
    {
        error = GetLastError();
        free(buffer);
        return NULL;
    }
    
    Utf8String* string = new Utf16String(static_cast<wchar_t*>(buffer), dwNumRead / sizeof(wchar_t));
    
    return string;
}
```

There is no reason to use `ReadFileEx()` in your example, since you are not actually processing the read asynchronously in the background.

> Can the way that's working be accepted as the proper way?

Yes, specifying the offset in the `OVERLAPPED` struct is the correct *and documented* way to go.

> Could I run into possible problems using the second method?

No.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I really like your answer it's just that the other guy expressed a bit more detail and insight into the essence of matters in relation to the question. Particularly elaborating on concurrency issues.